# I want to know how can I run phonegap application in the background for pushnotification?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am new in phonegap .

I want to know how can I run phonegap application in the background? 
I need when I click back button my application run in background and get push notification from the server .

Please help me .

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to "run the app the background"
You just need to implement `PushWoosh` or `PushPlugin` which are push notifications plugins available for Phonegap and Phonegap Build
A quick Google search for any of those two returns the required information.

However those plugins will be able to get the data from GCM (android) or APN (iOS)
and with a javascript code (you can check the example code in PushPlugin) to do the appropriate action when the push notification is clicked.

And you also need to send to the GCM server the push notification data (also check example code + you need to set up your Google APIs + much more complex procedure for APN)

So basically:

1. Server sends data to GCM/APN
2. phone receives data from GCM/APN
3. Phone displays push notification
4. User clicks on it
5. you do the appropriate action using PushPlugin javascript code

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jud joubran. I created my own push notification server for sending push notification. The problem is that when my application is open that time i get push notification but when i close my application that time i dont get any push notification for that reason i need to run my application in background.

Comment: Which plugin are you using?

Comment: It used to work with me when I was using push plugin. Try to use PushWoosh instead

Comment: When I close my application and remove from recent area that time I don't get any notification. For that reason I need to run my application in the background. If you have any phonegap plugin for background services please help me . I use some native code also background services but I don't get success code:  super.setBooleanProperty("keepRunning", true);